# Laravel 5.8.16 Class 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager' not found error

Tags: php, laravel, mailing

I have trouble when I try to send Mail.
My code to send mail:

```
$data = $request->all();
$result = Mail::to(env('MAIL_ADMIN'))->send(new ContactFormMail($data['name'],$data['email']));
```

ContactFormMail is my controller with code below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactFormMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $name;
    protected $email;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($name, $email)
    {

        $this->name=$name;
        $this->email=$email;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.contact-form')
            ->with([
                'name'=>$this->name,
                'email'=>$this->email,
            ])
            ->subject('New mail');
    }
}
```

I have error on file

> /home/mpfmfoff/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueServiceProvider.php

```
protected function registerManager()
{
    $this->app->singleton('queue', function ($app) {
        // Once we have an instance of the queue manager, we will register the various
        // resolvers for the queue connectors. These connectors are responsible for
        // creating the classes that accept queue configs and instantiate queues.
        return tap(new QueueManager($app), function ($manager) {
            $this->registerConnectors($manager);       // Here I have error
        });  
    });
}
```

> "Class 'Illuminate\Queue\QueueManager' not found"

Comment: Can you try running `composer update`?

Comment: I can see that the class exists: https://github.com/illuminate/queue/blob/master/QueueManager.php